# How to check if file inside XAP exists?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I'm writing a Windows Phone 7 Application that loads sample data from XML files deployed inside the XAP. These XML files are localized, so there is on file for each culture supported.

Structure:

```
SampleData.xml
SampleData.de.xml
SampleData.fr.xml
SampleData.it.xml
...
```

The name of the XML to load is based on the current UI culture. It's easy to build the name of the file, but how do I check if a localized version of the current UI culture exists?

System.IO.File.Exists() is not available in Windows Phone 7. I could create a dummy file for each culture that is supported by the phone, but that's quite ugly, error prone and does not allow a fallback to the neutral language. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK there is no way to enumerate the files contained within a XAP file. Since you're the one creating the XAP you should know what files exist and which ones don't. If you're trying to load the localized version, or fall back to a default version if the former doesn't exist, then, instead of enumerating files in the package, you could create another file that lists all the localized versions available.

Alternately, you could use something like `XDocument.Load()` within a try-catch. It'll probably throw a `FileNotFoundException` which you can handle and then load the default version.

Answer (score 3):

```
private bool IsFileExists(string relativePath)
{
    return Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri(relativePath, UriKind.Relative)) != null;
}
```

relativePath should NOT begin with a slash

Answer (score 1):

If the file is marked with build action "Resource" then you have to prefix your local path with "/;component/" string to load resource successfully.

```
return Application.GetResourceStream(new Uri("/PhoneProject1;component/" + relativePath, UriKind.Relative)) != null;
```